# Django Admin is not showing X out of X selected and the link to select all

Tags: django, django-admin

For some reason after I upgrade django to 3.2.21, when I select all records in the admin page, it's no longer showing 100 out of 100 records selected and providing the link to select all records across multiple paginated pages.

I'm not doing anything special in the admin class, just set  list_display, list_filter, list_display_links, and actions.

Anyone knows what might be wrong?

**EDIT:
In HTMl I actually do found the links, etc are there but the css is setting the display to none for span.question, thus the link is not shown.
Anyone has any clues on why this is the case?**
[image]

Comment: What was your old Django version and do you have any 3rd party package installed which is related to Django admin customization?

Comment: I actually also just tried to revert the django version but still no luck. Yes, I am using django-3-jet, but I doubt that's the issue as it was working fine previously with django-3-jet

Comment: Try to run the server in a different port to see if this solves the issue.

Comment: Tried locally and get the same issue for a new port. I was able to select all records in the table in the current page, and execute the actions on them. Just the select all link is not showing to allow me select all records across multiple pages and execute the action

Comment: if I tried to run it locally with debug = false, without --secure flag and using a new port, the page is loaded without css & js, and I do see the link for select all is shown. So looks like this is an issue with the css so that hide the select all link somehow?

Comment: In HTMl I actually do found the links, etc are there but the css is setting the display to none for span.question, thus the link is not shown. Do you think this is due to the 3rd party package?

Answer (score 0):

After some research, looks like this is indeed an issue with django 3.2.X versions: https://github.com/douglasmiranda/django-admin-bootstrap/issues/156. After revert to previous 3.1.X version and changed port, it worked like a charm.